# Can't able to create createFileInfos for an Asset using Azure PHP sdk

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I'm trying to create `createFileInfos` for an asset that i copied from existing blob. I can able to create a asset and copy a blob to a newly created asset. But i tried to create `createFileInfos`  files for this asset but its not creating. I'm using PHP sdk. Am i missing anything here?

Sample code:

```
$asset = new Asset(Asset::OPTIONS_NONE);//Asset creation
$assetname = 'myasset';
$asset->setName($assetname);
$asset = $this->_mediaService->createAsset($asset);

$access = new AccessPolicy($assetPolicyName);//Access Policy
$access->setDurationInMinutes(6000);
$access->setPermissions(AccessPolicy::PERMISSIONS_WRITE);
$access = $this->_mediaService->createAccessPolicy($access);

$locator = new Locator($asset, $access, Locator::TYPE_SAS);//Locator
$locator->setStartTime(new \DateTime('now -5 minutes'));
$locator = $this->_mediaService->createLocator($locator);

$asset = $this->getAssetByName($assetname);
$destinationContainer = <newly created assset container>;
$destinationBlob = <filename>;
$sourceContainer = <my source blob>;
$sourceBlob = <source filename>;
$blobRestProxy->copyBlob($destinationContainer, $destinationBlob, $sourceContainer, $sourceBlob); // Copying Blob
$this->_mediaService->createFileInfos($asset); // trying to create asset info files
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this maybe due to old version of Blob REST API used in PHP SDK. The way you createFileInfos is correct. Could you try this fix in our dev branch: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/commit/972e09c74308411602027280ededb3048b1e2fc4 to see whether you could make the upload working?

Cheers,
Mingfei Yan